# Order of evaluation of function arguments

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html):

> **Exercise 3.8**
>
> When we defined the
>   evaluation model in section 1.1.3, we
>   said that the first step in evaluating
>   an expression is to evaluate its
>   subexpressions. But we never specified
>   the order in which the subexpressions
>   should be evaluated (e.g., left to
>   right or right to left). When we
>   introduce assignment, the order in
>   which the arguments to a procedure are
>   evaluated can make a difference to the
>   result. Define a simple procedure f
>   such that evaluating `(+ (f 0) (f 1))`
>   will return 0 if the arguments to +
>   are evaluated from left to right but
>   will return 1 if the arguments are
>   evaluated from right to left.

I wrote this solution:

```
(define it false)
(define (f x)
  (if it
      it
      (begin (set! it (/ x 2)) it)))

(+ (f 1) (f 0))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns 1/2 if the `(f 0)` is evaluated first, not 0. A better way would be to return the last argument to `f`, with a default of 0.

```
(define last 0)
(define (f x)
  (define temporary last)
  (set! last x)
  temporary
)
```

When `(+ (f 0) (f 1))` is evaluated with `(f 0)` first, execution is as follows:

1. `f` is called with 0
2. `temporary` is set to 0 (the default `last`)
3. `last` is set to 0 (the argument to f)
4. `temporary` (0) is returned
5. `f` is called with 1
6. `temporary` is set to 0
7. `last` is set to 1
8. `temporary` (0) is returned
9. 0+0=0

If `(f 1)` is evaluated first, then execution is as follows:

1. `f` is called with 1
2. `temporary` is set to 0 (the default `last`)
3. `last` is set to 1 (the argument to f)
4. `temporary` (0) is returned
5. `f` is called with 0
6. `temporary` is set to 1
7. `last` is set to 0
8. `temporary` (1) is returned
9. 0+1=1

Comment: I agree - returning the last argument is cleaner than my solution.  I don't think that my answer returned 0.5 though - it computes 0/2 (which is 0) and then returns that twice - so it should still be correct?  Anyway, I like your solution better.  Thanks!

Comment: @jaresty You're right, it would return 0. I thought 0 was considered false, but was wrong.